# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Buenas tardes a todos. Estoy teniendo problemas para crear una base de datos. Ya que obtengo el error

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

Desde el SuperUsuario (sa) le he dado permisos al usuario "Lucas" con db_owner para que pueda crear bases de datos pero aun asi el error persiste.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Solucionado. Me falto marcarlo como sysadmin en Server Roles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Enhorabuena por haber solucionado el problema por tí solo. Eso se merece un premio: +1 :)

Comment: Gracias en serio me sirvio como solucionaste tu problema

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo la práctica recomendada de no dar más acceso de lo necesario, si el usuario solo necesita poder crear nuevos database, puedes darle el server role `dbcreator`.

Como comentó @jachguate, tampoco necesitas asignarle `db_owner` del database `master`. Así que, si puedes evitar esto también, es buena idea.

Si le das el server role `sysadmin`, también funciona por supuesto, pero también le estarás dando acceso al servidor de base de datos por entero.

Escoge el server role que sea más apropiado en tu caso.

Comment: creo que hace falta aclarar que tampoco tiene por que tener el db_owner sobre la base de datos master, con el rol a nivel de servidor basta.

Comment: @jachguate: Oh sí! Muy importante ese detalle. Gracias.